# Allow popper.js for dropdowns in navbar on Bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar, dropdown, popper.js

Does anyone know how to allow popper.js for dropdowns in navbar on Bootstrap 4?

Comment: What do you mean by allowing it? Why do you think it's not allowed? What problem are you facing? Can you show a code example?

Comment: It's disabled for navbars by default from Bootstrap.

Comment: Dropdowns [work correctly](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/#supported-content) inside a navbar, so I don't understand you.

Comment: Indeed, they work correctly, but I need popper.js for dynamic positioning and viewport detection.

Comment: @Jared yes, you need to look for this code in bootstrap.js

 _proto._detectNavbar = function _detectNavbar() {
      return $(this._element).closest('.navbar').length > 0;
    };

Answer (score 1):

It is old question, but it could help to someone. Bootstrap says: *Popper.js isn’t used to position dropdowns in navbars though as dynamic positioning isn’t required.* But in my usecase it is required, so @doublet2 answer helped me a lot. It is little hacky but it fix this problem ..
*window.bootstrap.Dropdown.prototype._detectNavbar = function(){ return false; };*