# What is context in css specificity?

Tags: html, css, css-specificity

I am reading this article on `@ layers` in css:  https://www.bram.us/2021/09/15/the-future-of-css-cascade-layers-css-at-layer/#cascade-layers--position-in-the-cascade

I can't find on google what is `context` in css. Can somebody explain to me what is it and also give some references?

Answer (score 0):

From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-5/#cascade-context)

> A document language can provide for blending declarations sourced from different encapsulation contexts, such as the nested tree contexts of shadow trees in the [DOM].
>
> When comparing two declarations that are sourced from different encapsulation contexts, then for normal rules the declaration from the outer context wins, and for important rules the declaration from the inner context wins. For this purpose, [DOM] tree contexts are considered to be nested in shadow-including tree order.

Comment: Thanks mate. Do you also work with bootstrap? I had a issue with implementing popper js in bootstrap nav, -- here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56198913/3429430